# ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "EcsLayout"

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j2

I am trying to set up ecs-logging for java project, using the guide https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/java/1.x/setup.html

Logs is been writing correctly when I run the project inside IntelleJ idea, but when I run the jar I got the exception:

```
ERROR File contains an invalid element or attribute "EcsLayout"
```

And no log is being created. I use java 17, but also tried 11 & 15 - no difference.

For ecs-logs I added 2 dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j2-ecs-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>co.elastic.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecs-logging-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

The log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="FILE_JSON" fileName="app-logs/dataloader.log" immediateFlush="false">
            <EcsLayout serviceName="Dataloader"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.idomoo" level="${env:LOG_LEVEL}" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE_JSON"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="*" level="ERROR" includeLocation="true" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE_JSON"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE_JSON"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I guess that there is some kind of dependency conflict (because an empty project with the same configuration works fine), but I can't resolve. Any help is much appreciated.

For log4j2 I use dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also the project contains lot of 'software.amazon.awssdk' dependencies, mysql-connector-java, mongodb-driver-sync, org.apache.commons.